# Unix Sort with exponential values

Tags: bash

I tried `-g` but still not sorting true my exp numbers :

```
sort -g output.out > sorted.out
```

and it gave me that output :

```
0.100159E+00 0.998410E+01   121.0000
0.100753E+00 0.992529E+01   126.8500
0.101409E+01 0.986102E+00   130.8000
0.102260E-01 0.977901E+02   123.4000
0.102844E+00 0.972347E+01   120.9500
0.107397E-02 0.931122E+03   124.0500
```

it seems like not sorting truely...

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `echo "$LC_NUMERIC"`

Comment: `sort -g output.out > sorted.out echo "$LC_NUMERIC"` like this  ?

Comment: No, only `echo "$LC_NUMERIC"`. Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LC_NUMERIC` locale determines the decimal-point character.

```
LC_ALL=C sort -g output.out > sorted.out
```

---

*Example*

```
$ echo "$LC_ALL"
de_DE

$ sort -g foo   
0.100159E+00 0.998410E+01   121.0000
0.100753E+00 0.992529E+01   126.8500
0.101409E+01 0.986102E+00   130.8000
0.102260E-01 0.977901E+02   123.4000
0.102844E+00 0.972347E+01   120.9500
0.107397E-02 0.931122E+03   124.0500

$ LC_ALL=C sort -g foo    
0.107397E-02 0.931122E+03   124.0500
0.102260E-01 0.977901E+02   123.4000
0.100159E+00 0.998410E+01   121.0000
0.100753E+00 0.992529E+01   126.8500
0.102844E+00 0.972347E+01   120.9500
0.101409E+01 0.986102E+00   130.8000
```